# Multiple UITableViews on one UIView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I need to have two UITableViews on one UIView.  I can make it work with one, here is the code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [contentOne count];  // sets row count to number of items in array
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *firstValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Row %i% %", indexPath.row+1 ];
    NSString *secondValue = [contentOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *cellValue = [firstValue stringByAppendingString: secondValue]; // appends two strings

    [cell.textLabel setText:cellValue];



    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

I have tried several different methods.  Anyone? If I could name each UITableView a different name that should do it but it will not let me edit tableView to anything else without crashing.

Comment: Duplicate Question Try the solution given in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11789681/846372

Answer (score 28, accepted):

so you need some way to tell the two `tableView`s apart--you could either set the "tag" property to different values, or have a property on your view controller that points to each view

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView2;
```

then hook these up to each view in interface builder...

then in your view controller methods you can do

```
(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
        return 37;
    } else if (tableView == self.tableView2) {
        return 19;
    } else {
        // shouldn't get here, use an assert to check for this if you'd like
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried 
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 if (tableView == self.tableOne){
    return 1;
 } 
 else if (tableView == self.tableTwo){
 return 1;
 } 
 else{

  return 1; 
 }
}


It gives me the error Local declaration of tableView hides instance

Comment: do you have a class variable named tableView?  is your class here derived from UITableViewController, or something else?

Comment: I did everything inside of the UIView.  I did not have a seperate controller for the UITableView.  I just tried sections and it is so much easier than trying to make two seperate UITableViews.  I was able to seperate my two arrays into seperate sections.  Thank you for helping.  I am just not getting it.

Comment: separate tableViews would be good if you wanted them to be separately scrollable...  if you want one list with two kinds of stuff in it then two sections in one list is the way to go.  It will start to make sense eventually!

Answer (score 14):

Probably the easiest way of implementing this is to have two delegate and data source classes, one for each table view.  That would reduce the number of if (tableview == tableview1) occurances in the view controller code.

Comment: Could you provide an example implementation for this please?

Comment: but it would multiply the number of delegate and data source methods to implement. it's a give and take scenario :)

Answer (score 5):

[This sample code](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/TwoTableViews/) might help you...