# Two UITableViews in one UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIView. It contain two UIScrollView, and everyone UIScrollView contains one UITableView.

When I fill tables with data, the first table gets filled with data, but the second table remains empty.

What could be wrong?

After debugging I saw that

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

was called for first table only. but

```
(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

was called for every table!!! --> also no problems with delegate or datasource...

Please Help.

I am using the logic :

```
if(tableView == self.tableU1){
  ... 
  } 
else{
...
}
```

for differentiate the tables.

Comment: Same happened to me, after a while I realised I forgot to call "reloadData" with the second table.

Answer (score 2):

This question may be relevant:

[iPad - More than one UITableView in the same screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858554/ipad-more-than-one-uitableview-in-the-same-screen)

You're absolutely sure you've hooked up both the delegate *and* the data source for *both* tables, right? Double check!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are setting delegate for both tables. And it must be your controller. If you are using Interface builder try to set delegate manualy:

```
tableView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have hinted at this, but note that cellForRowAtIndexPath: is a *datasource* method, while viewForHeaderInSection: is a *delegate* method. It seems almost definite that you've hooked up your delegate to both, both only your datasource to one.

Comment: also you right. but in IB datasource is set. and programmaticly i have not hooked up any datasource. in viewDidLoad i set for second table datasourde as follow:

[[self tableU2] setDataSource:self]; 

its right so?

Comment: Is the one that's not working the one that's set in IB or the one that's set programmatically? Also, check that tableU2 is an IBOutlet and connected to the table itself... otherwise [self tableU2] will return nil, and the datasource will never be set.