# Two UITableView in the same view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to know if it's allowed to use Multiple `UItableView` in the same View (i don't see any thing in the [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/)) and if it's OK, How to load different `DataSource` in `viewDidLoad` for each `UITableView`?

Comment: Try this where you find sample Code with full explanation of 2 different approaches to do this: See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11789681/846372

Answer (score 20):

You can most certainly have multiple table views. You would want to make sure you keep a pointer around to each one, then in your data source methods, you would do something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     if(tableView == tableViewOne)
           return 5;
     else //if (tableView == tableViewTwo)
           return 3;
}
```

This would be the same for all delegate / data source methods, which is why they give you which table view as a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. The issue is that each `UITableView` will use the same `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`. Therefore you must determine which table view you are working with in each of the necessary delegate methods.

For example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // make bigger rows

    if (tableView == myBigRowTableView)
    {
        // make bigger rows
        return 127;
    } else if (tableView == mySmallRowTableView) {
        // make smaller rows
        return 20;
    } else {
        return 30;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just make sure you are providing a default value, either by having a default return type at the end, or by having your last if clause be just else, otherwise you'll get compiler warnings.

Answer (score 5):

IMO the cleanest solution would be to have one controller for each tableview.

If you use one controller for n tableview, you will have to use if-statemenst in many places,
in

- `– numberOfSectionsInTableView:`
- `– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`
- `– tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`
- …

Basically in all UITableViewDatasource-Protocol methods that you will need to implement.

So if you need to change something, you have to change it in many places.

If you use one controller class for one tableview, you won't have to check at all.

1. write a controller class for every tableview, make it conforming to the `UITableViewDatasource` protocol

   - implement the protocol methods you will need. at least

     - `– numberOfSectionsInTableView:`,
     - `– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`,
     - `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
2. call `-setDataSource:`for every tableview to an object of the right controller class

I wrote an example code: https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/TwoTableViews

TwoTableViewsViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (firstController == nil) {
        firstController = [[FirstTVContoller alloc] init];
    }
    if (secondController == nil) {
        secondController = [[SecondTVController alloc] init];
    }
    [firstTable setDataSource:firstController];
    [secondTable setDataSource:secondController];

    [firstTable setDelegate:firstController];
    [secondTable setDelegate:secondController];
    firstController.view = firstController.tableView;
    secondController.view = secondController.tableView;
}
```

Comment: Big fan of this method.  Much cleaner and more organized.

Comment: There is no need to invoke additional view controllers and load new views.  You can can create 2 classes that adopt the <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ... > and other protocols you may need for your tables.  Create those delegates as properties on your main view controller. Then, either in code or in an XIB file, you can assign those as the respective delegate and datasource to your 2 two tables.  It is similar to the approach outlined above, but there is no need to add the complexity of more controllers and views to your hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

You can set tag for each table. Then apply on that condition in tableview delegate method, for example:

```
myTable.tag=12;
```

Answer (score 2):

To make life easier, you can pass in two different delegate to the UITableView.  If you pass in the same delegate, you will have to do a lot of if statements.  By creating two different delegate it will allow your code to be a lot cleaner.

Comment: This is often not the best practice though, as you would have to have multiple classes to do this. Code should be put where it makes the most sense to put it, not where it will save the programmer typing.

Comment: @Christian, putting code in another class doesn't save typing. Separating code is called **Encapsulation**.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple table views in a single view. Add tags to each table view and with use of tableview.tag you can load data into tableviews separately.

Example:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     if (tableView.tag == x) {
        //code to load table view with tag value x

        }
        else{
        //code to load second table
        }
        return cell;

    }
```