# Populating Two UITableView in the same View

Tags: iphone, uitableview, datasource, viewdidload

I have 2 UITableView in the same View and my question is how to populate them with different data in the `viewDidLoad` method? thanks.

Comment: First, you do not populate the data in viewDidLoad. You use the tableView's data source and delegate call backs. Second, your question was already answered in your last post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747889/two-uitableview-in-the-same-view

Comment: In my case i use a plist file and all tutorials i see, use this method! how can i use differents plist files to populate them?

Answer (score 0):

You populate them in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and in that function you can compare the tableView to see what table it is, and load the appropriate data for that table.

```
//Assume the following property
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *myData;
```

add this to the Code file

```
- (NSDictionary) myData
{
    if (myData == nil) //Notice I am accessing the variable, not the property accessor.
    {
        NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someName" ofType:@"plist"];
        myData = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath] retain];
    }
    return myData;
}
```

then when you access the self.myData property it will open up if it is not opened already.

Comment: Ok, i can use if (tableView==table1)...else, but i don't know how to use plist files to populate them?

Comment: load a plist into a NSDictionary or an NSArray... You will need to determine off the NSIndexPath how to populate the cell.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the plist part of your question:

```
NSString *filePath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someName" ofType:@"plist"] retain];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath] retain];
```

So just use two of these, one for each table, then just have two tableView, as it appears you already understand.

Comment: Ok, thanks but where to put this? in which method? in general i put it in viewDidLoad method, but it seems that other experienced programmers saids that it's Wrong!

Comment: add a lazy load method to a property. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: I dont know why that person is anti- `viewDidLoad` - I would definitely put this in `viewDidLoad` and I have in past apps and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

All delegate and datasource protocol methods always pass a pointer to the tablesView they are called for. Just do an if to check which is meant in each method.