# Display TableViews corresponding to segmentedControl in a single tableview without pushing a new view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a tableViewController where I have used the Interface Builder to insert a Segmented Controller having two segments. Since by default, first segment is always selected, I am not facing any problem in displaying the tableview corresponding to first segment. However, when I click on the second segment, I want to display another tableView.

Here goes the problem.
I am calling newTableViewController class on clicking the second segment. Hence, this view is getting pushed instead. Please suggest me a method to have these two tableViews in the main tableView upon clicking the segments.

I have used switch case for switching between the segments.

Here's the relevant part of the code:
This method is in the FirstTableViewController since first segment is by default selected.

```
-(IBAction) segmentedControlChanged
{
     switch(segmentedControl.selectedSegmnentIndex)
     {
        case 0:
         //default first index selected. 
         [tableView setHidden:NO];
         break;
         case 1:
         NewViewController *controller=[[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
         self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
         [controller release];
         break;
         default:
         break;
     }
}
```

Comment: take two tableviews in one class. Why are you taking two classes?

Comment: do the condition check where you want to display the tableview content..In that do the two different tasks according to `segmentedControl.selectedSegmnentIndex`

Answer (score 2):

Put below code, as first line of  **case 1:**

```
if(self.tblView.isHidden==NO)
    self.tblView.hidden=YES;
```

as like,,,

```
case 1:
         if(self.tblView.isHidden==NO)
              self.tblView.hidden=YES;

         NewViewController *controller=[[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
         self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
         [controller release];
         break;
```

Comment: doesnt work...it's still getting pushed to NewViewcontroller upon clicking the second segment.

Answer (score 1):

You should create two or more `UITableViews` in the same class or better create different arrays for a single `UITableView` and then use conditions to add the arrays to the same table. I hope you got my point. You shouldn't go with the different classes method until and unless it is really essential.

Also this would save you the hassle of importing different `UITableViews` from different classes reducing your memory management too.

Comment: Okay so please tell me whether I got that straight. I have to create two tableViews in the same tableViewController. So everything I have written in the NewViewController should be brought to this old ViewController and everytime I need to use this viewController I need to add the condition: if(tableView==tableViewOne) { firsttableView  } else second TableView

Comment: Exactly.... u have to mention which tableView u hav to display according to the segment...

Answer (score 1):

To add Two tableview in same class, you have to use Tag for UITableView. Set Tag and upload data as per selected Segment.

I think [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747889/two-uitableview-in-the-same-view)
is having same issue.

Edit.
**There are multiple options**

1. If table structure/ look is same, you can use two array as input and can use.
2. You can use Two different UITableView with conditions or use Tag for Table View

Answer (score 1):

1.Create one view controller say: MainViewController inherits UIViewController(not UITableViewController).

2.In MainViewController create two tableView say mTableView1 and mTableView2 and assign tag to both the tableview say 100 and 101 respectively.

3.Create one variable which will store the value based on segment selected say if first segment is selected then var = 100 and so.

4.In tableview datasource and delegate methods use this var to find out which segment is selected, and display respective tableview.

And if your tableview structure and functionality is same then you can even use single tableview and pass data to display in tableview depending upon segment selected.

Code:
In viewDidLoad add following code:

```
m_TableView1 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
m_TableView1.tag = 100;
    m_TableView1.dataSource = self;
    m_TableView1.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview: m_TableView1];
    [m_TableView1 release];



m_TableView2 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
m_TableView2.tag = 101;
    m_TableView2.dataSource = self;
    m_TableView2.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview: m_TableView2];
    [m_TableView2 release];
```

Then in datasource and delegate methods use tag and provide appropriate data as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            }
    if(tableView.tag == 100)
       cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"First table, cell%d",indexPath.row];
   else
     cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"Second table, cell%d",indexPath.row];

}
```

Comment: Actually I have two tableViews and there are different functionalities in both the tableviews and there are service methods as well. So if I not wrong, I would have to check the tableView condition in each and every method separately?

Comment: Yes, if your tableviews are different and performed different functionality then you have to check the tableview condition ex: in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection etc

Comment: But how m I gonna call the viewDidLoad method of the 2nd tableViewController? 
Because in the viewDidLoad of this viewController I am writing the code to load the first view as it is by default selected

Answer (score 0):

Change this way:

1>Take one Tableview and Segmentation Control by default first segment is selected and First Table view is front View and set its userinteraction false

2>When Second segment is selected hide first tableview and send back the old tableview 
and bring the second table view front and make it visible set its userinteraction true

Comment: It would really help if you write the basic code for understanding it better :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction) segmentedControlChanged
{
     switch(segmentedControl.selectedSegmnentIndex)
     {
        case 0:
         //default first index selected. 
         [tableView setHidden:NO];
      if([self.view viewWithTag:9999]){
      [[self.view viewWithTag:9999]removeFromSuperView]; //remove other table
     }
}
         break;
         case 1:
         NewViewController *controller=[[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
         [self.view addSubView:controller.view];
        [controller.view setTag:9999];
         break;
         default:
         break;
     }
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: NewViewController is another tableViewController. So I'm not sure whether this condition will call all of the newviewController's methods and load the view on clicking on the second segment

Comment: set the delegate of newViewcontroller to itself..if you want to call its delegate methods separately

Comment: I do not want the segmented control to disappear. It should remain the way it is so that I can switch between the views.