# Adding a split view controller to a single view project in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an application that is working quite well, but the customer wants to combine two of the views (UIViewControllers) in to a single view (a Split View Controller).

The master part of the view will be a table with a list of Staff in a TableView, and the detail view will be made up of two Table Views - one that contains details about the member of staff (name, phone, ext, office etc) and the other with training records (courses, qualifications and so forth).

When you click on the master table, it selects the detail records for the given member of staff and displays them in the detail view.

I have no storyboard in the application, and use [self presentViewContoller] to switch from view to view (because there is a lot of conditional processing on what view is required and a storyboard seemed to be too restrictive)

However I have tried the following :-

Creating a SplitViewController (right click, New File, UISplitViewController), but it seems to be empty with no master or detail views. Also, when I try to make it appear, it either doesn't appear, or causes it to crash (tried to present a SplitViewController modally).

Creating a "fake" split view controller, by putting two views on a normal view controller, then putting the required tables inside them. However I can not find a way to present any borders or the like, and the whole thing looks a tad unprofessional and stupid.

So my question is basically this :-

Is it possible to create SplitViewControllers in single view projects, and use them?

Or, if not, is it possible to put borders around views, or tables, or draw a single straight line on a view?

(If at all possible, I would prefer not to have to rewrite my entire application and just add this SplitView controller or the "fake split view Controller")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use container views:

Create a new root view controller and add two container views to it. This will create two embed segues that you can point to the view controller's whose views you want to appear in these containers.

Comment: This is more or less what I have - a controller with two views (although I now have three views - one coloured black, and two views on that view coloured white - it's how I am getting round the border issues) and the tables in the views - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control two UIViewController simultaneously.
So, try displaying two UIView or subclasses of UIView like UITableView.
Displaying Two UITableView is a little tiresome.
Take a look at this question [Two UITableView in the same view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747889/two-uitableview-in-the-same-view)

As for borders around views, you can put UIImageView or something as border lines.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(159, 0, 2, 640)];
```

Comment: The table view stuff seems to be the least of my worries, but thanks for the link.