# UITableView: Multiple tables: how to disable deletion of cell for a single table?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a view controller with 2 table views A and B. In table A, i want to enable deletion of cells, in table B, i want to disable deletion of cells.

Implementing `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath{}` will enable the deletion (when a cell is swiped to the left, the deletion button appears) on all table views in the view controller.

How can I disable this for a single table?

Comment: Might be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747889/two-uitableview-in-the-same-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement below delegate method as something like:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == tableViewA)
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    else
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` method is for committing an editing in a `UITableView`, so it will be called if the user invoke the editing action.

Answer (score 0):

`commitEditingStyle` function has a parameter `tableView`. You can assign different tags to your tableView and detect them inside this function - and return YES for one and NO for another.

Comment: although this function has a return type of VOID ?