# how can create more than one UITableView in a UIViewController programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.3

I want to create 2 UITableView programmatically in a UIViewController. I have 2 NSMutableArray for the datas which are *firstTableDatas and *secondTableDatas. I can manage to create one UITableView programmatically but when it becomes 2 then I am confused what will be the return values for the 2 UITableView for the delegates:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
}
```

and

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
```

and how can i load the datas in 2 individual UITableView s.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this where you find sample Code with full explanation of 2 different approaches to do this: See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11789681/846372

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
if(tableView ==Firsttable)
{
...
}
else
{
...
}
```

in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check like below:

```
if(tableView ==firstTableDatas)
{
    //Code related to First Table
}
else if(tableView ==secondTableDatas)
{
    //Code related to Second Table
}
```

It will work in UITableViewDelegate methods.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

give diff tag to both the tableView and on the bases of there tags do the required function

for example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      if(tableView.tag==1)
      {
          return 100;
      }
      else if(tableView.tag==2)
      {
           return 50;
      }
      return 40;
}
```