# How to implement 2 tables in a single view (Not sectioned Table)

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can we create 2 table views in a single view without using section TableViews..,
I just want to display two tableViews in the view screen.., Say.., I have dragged two UITableViews from the Interface Builder to my view screen.., and i connected the IBOutlet defined in interface file.., AFAIK, we need to define two methods in the implementation file.. i.e.., numberOfRows and numberOfSections.., But I am confused.., doing that will change the tableView property of both the tables...

EDITED:

I want to create a horizontal scroll view..,with 3 tableViews of size 320 X 200.., 
What I did was dragged UIScrollView to the view in IB.., Then dragged 3 UITableViews into that scrollView.., What do I need to do next., to fill up the table contents ?

Comment: can u be more brief with ur question.

Comment: Could you at least provide some mockup or layout? It is pretty hard to get the idea

Comment: I just want to display two tableViews in the view screen.., 
Say.., I have dragged two UITableViews from the Interface Builder to my view screen.., and i connected the IBOutlet defined in interface file.., 
AFAIK, we need to define two methods in the implementation file.. i.e.., numberOfRows and numberOfSections.., But I am confused.., doing that will change the tableView property of both the tables...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple UITableViews on one UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416372/multiple-uitableviews-on-one-uiview)

Comment: @Vladimir, thanks for pointing that its a dup. I answered without knowing that.

Comment: possible Duplicate Question http://stackoverflow.com/a/11448126/846372

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Table views are `UIView`. So you can add multiple table view as subview just like you can add multiple labels or buttons. However, if you want to use the same object as delegate for both table views then a little more work is needed. All the delegate methods are passed the table view for which the method has been called as the first parameter. You need to check that parameter to know for which table view the method is called. For example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
        return [arrayForView1 count];
    }

    if (tableView == self.tableView2) {
        return [arrayForView2 count];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks...That was great.. One more query... Have edited the question.., May be.., You could understand my question

Comment: You will do all those things that you did for one single table. You only need to know for which table the delegate methods has been called. You can do that by using the process in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag two table view inside your view, and set those dataSource and delegate to files owner.

Comment: But defining...numberOfRows and numberOfSections..,will change the tableView property of both the tables ???

Comment: @KPK, yes they will affect both tables unless you check the table for which the method is called in the delegate methods.

Comment: @kpk:the proper solution is in first answer  @taskinoor: thanks, I escape this part

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you, you want to display different data in the two table views? If so, just create a viewcontroller with xib file, setup the two tableviews inside this xib file.

Then, you create two tableviewcontrollers (one for each tableview) without xib file.

Create instances of these tableviewcontrollers in the viewcontroller and set the delegate / data-source relations programatically.

Should work so far but I don't think users will like this^^