# load multiple uitableviews when app starts

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4.5

I am new to iOS development and this is my first app. I am working on a Master-Detail iPad app.The flow of the app is: When the app starts,a list of 'departments' is displayed in a table.When the user selects a 'department',another table is displayed with a list of all the 'documents' for the selected department.When the user selects the 'document' cell,the document is opened in the detailview in read-only mode. I am loading the 'document' table only after the 'department' cell is selected. Is there any way I can populate the 'document' table when the app starts(in the app delegate?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Navigation based application** and reload the table as per your requirement

Comment: Navigation based application sample tutorial is here http://gigaom.com/apple/iphone-dev-sessions-create-a-navigation-based-application/

Comment: you can change the Uitableview delegates asper your conditions

Comment: then you can reload the document table and check the table in delegate

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416372/multiple-uitableviews-on-one-uiview