# Configuring Multiple UITableViews In One View?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have been faced with a puzzle I can't answer.

I am creating an app that has multiple `UITableView` within a single view.  Each `TableView` will need to have different attributes from the other.

The `UITableViewDelegate` methods provide generic methods to configure `UITableView`s, but from what I am seeing, this will effect aLL `TableViews` within a View.

If I need to control the parameters for each single `TableView` - how would this be achieved?

Comment: Don't set your viewcontroller as delegate and datasource, instead create a nsobject subclass for each tableview and set them. It will be much more easier to manage and maintain.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1416372/1075405

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not correct - you can configure everything with a `UITableViewDelegate`. Take for example:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

You can differentiate the tableviews via the `tableView` variable. For this you need to store a reference to the different tableviews (e.g. via a property).

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *myFirstTableView;
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
if (tableView == self.myFirstTableView) {} else {}
```

Answer (score 0):

for each of the delegate methods, its giving you which tableview it needs information. you can use that to identify which instance of the tableview requesting data..

use a tag to differentiate table views.

```
   tableview1.tag = 100;
    tableview2.tag = 200;
   // ... so on - if using interface builder you can set tag in there too :)
```

now in delegate.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
if (tableview.tag == 100)
{
// handle for tableview 1
}
else if (tableview.tag == 200)
{
// handle for tableview 2
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your tableView delegate methods starts with `tableView` as parameter.

Ex: `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

This passes UITableView as parameter. Therefore, you can add switch-case or if statements to check for which tableView you want to modify data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the UIViewController as your tableView delegate, you could create a new class to act as tableView delegate. This class can then contain the parameters needed for the specific table that it is handling.

Inside the view controller you can then allocate one instance of this class per tableView and assign it as delegate.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback and ideas.  Have got it sorted.